# How to animate a line so that it gets bigger?

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, cgrect

I created just a blank project in Xcode and added a button. I centered it and set its height and width to 60. Heres my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    
    var lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 60, width: 5, height: 1))
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        button.addSubview(lineView)
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func sampleButton(_ sender: Any) {
        
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0, animations: {
                
                self.lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 60, width: self.button.frame.width, height: 1))
                self.button.addSubview(self.lineView)
        
            }, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
}
```

When I click the button I want the width to go from being 5 pixels to the width of the button which is 60. I also want to animate this but I am having trouble. So far when I click the button nothing happens. Would anyone be able to help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create a new view.  Just change the frame of the one you already have:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0, animations: {
    
    self.lineView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 60, width: self.button.frame.width, height: 1)

}, completion: nil)
```